# Where is Settings.apk on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 (4.4.2)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, samsung

I can't find Settings.apk file in /system/app directory. I use the latest stock firmware. Where can I find this APK on this device?

Comment: You can try to do an adb backup (with `-system -apk` of course) and see if the apk is in the backup. If it isn't, then I don't think it's in any accessible location.

Comment: Look also for `/system/priv-app`. I forget when that started to be used for system APKs, but it may have been there in 4.4.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young : But that will only tell us that Settings.apk exists. How is it gonna tell us the location of it?

Comment: If your device is rooted (I assume that, since you can browse the `/system/app` folder), try file manager that has search feature, like ES File Explorer. When I searched it on Nexus 5 (Lollipop), it's on `/system/priv-app/Settings/` just like the answer below... or Samsung doesn't name it as `Settings.apk`. Instead, could you explain a little why you want to find that APK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, in `kitkat(and up)` it maybe deleted from above address but,

I found this on `Lollipop 5.0.2` in :

> `/system/priv-app/Settings/Settings.apk`

Hope you can find it.

---

**Edit** : file founded in `KitKat`-`emulator` ***(API-19)*** with below address :

> `/system/priv-app/Settings.apk`

**Proof :**

[image]

Comment: I've checked — the only related to Settings apk is SecSettings.apk in this directory.

Comment: check my answer please, Updated.

Comment: I believe you, but unfortunately my question is related to Samsung device, not vanilla Android. My directory listing looks like this: http://pastebin.com/H5WbnDKb

Comment: it was on `4.4.2 KitKat` not `vanilla`... anyway, i find this and also : `settings.jar` in `/system/framework`. hope , it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. "vanilla" kernel/OS means "original", without any vendor changes. For example, Android SDK or Nexus devices have "vanilla" android :)

Comment: ok :) but, can i ask you why this file important for you ? if you cant find it at The future, try or flash stock rom and check it again, maybe this file deleted or something like that.but i already installed `5.0.2` and this problem not exist,(as i said, i find it) this is intresting on kitkat.